# Approve edits that only add a conclusion?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently bumped into two edits that *only* added a boldfaced **Very unlikely** and **Yes, roughly** to the beginning of the answer.

Personally, I'm in favor of this clarity (especially with long answers), but I see many answers where the original author refrained from such conclusions, for whatever reason.

So:

- Reject as *No difference whatsoever*?
- Reject as *Conflicts with authors' intent*?
- Judge on a case by case basis, like with a long answer having no clear conclusion?

Notes:

- Having read the opinions in [Can we please discourage drawing absolute conclusions from single studies?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/can-we-please-discourage-drawing-absolute-conclusions-from-single-studies), let's assume that a decent amount of material is quoted.
- Some (elaborate) answers have comments asking things like 'Does this prove or debunk the claim'? This question does not apply to those.
- Not relevant: [When is an edit "too minor" to be accepted?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/when-is-an-edit-too-minor-to-be-accepted)

Answer (score 1):

The answers should be correct and balanced when presenting conclusions, and at the same time be bold and clear on what the evidence means.

As long as these edits go in the right direction (correct and clear), they are fine and should be accepted. If they overstate the case or misrepresent what the author clearly meant (e.g. going from "Yes" to "No"), then they should be rejected. In the middle, it's really up to your judgement: we trust you!